# Can't refresh access token for Sonos

Tags: sonos

When trying to refresh the access token when it expires, had an error:

Access Denied
You don't have permission to access "http://api.sonos.com/auth/oauth/v2/access" on this server.
Reference #18.cc5e0e17.1539959683.3844201.

Using request from Sonos API reference: https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/refresh-token/

Authorization the same as in "Create token" request, and it works. And refresh token is from responce to "Create token" request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got the wrong URL. The path should be /login/v3/oauth/access. We did have a mistake in our documentation which likely led to your error.